# Set different color for each bubble in Bubble-Map

Tags: highcharts

In Higchart's **[Bubble-Map](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/map-bubble)** chart, Is it possible to set different color for each bubble ? If yes then please update this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adhikariaman01/40n7jywg/) link.

```
series : [{
            name: 'Countries',
            mapData: mapData,
            color: '#E0E0E0',
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }, {
            type: 'mapbubble',
            mapData: mapData,
            //color : 'red' // This color applies for all the bubbles but i want different color for each bubble
            name: 'Population 2013',
            joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
            data: data,
            minSize: 4,
            maxSize: '12%',
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.z} thousands'
            }
        }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the color in the data string, eg

```
var data = [{
       code: "AF",
       z: 30552,
       color: '#642288'
    }, /*.... etc */
]
```

Since the data in the example is being loaded from elsewhere, I copied it into the fiddle and added the colors.

[Updated JS Fiddl](https://jsfiddle.net/40n7jywg/1/)

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. Thanks !